Does anicca mean inconstancy? Or dissolution?
I read the following on the internet:

Anicca means inconstancy - the aggregates are constantly changing and thus unreliable, making them stressful.

Does anicca primarily mean inconstancy, i.e., the aggregates continue to exist but fluctuate, including getting 'reborn'? Or does anicca primarily mean the aggregates are subject to both change & dissolution? Please offer quotes from the Pali Suttas to support different interpretations.

It appears the word 'anicca' primarily refers to impermanence rather than to Thanissaro's misleading translation of 'inconstancy'.

impermanence
noun
the state or fact of lasting for only a limited period of time.
"she describes the impermanence of human existence"


Inconstancy means changeability, not sticking to a predetermined
course.

For example:

Jarāmaraṇaṁ, bhikkhave, aniccaṁ saṅkhataṁ paṭiccasamuppannaṁ khayadhammaṁ vayadhammaṁ virāgadhammaṁ nirodhadhammaṁ.
Old age and death are impermanent, conditioned, dependently originated, liable to end, vanish, fade away and cease.
SN 12.20


Form, Ānanda, is impermanent, conditioned, dependently arisen, subject
to destruction, to vanishing, to fading away, to cessation. Through
its cessation, cessation is spoken of.
Feeling is impermanent … Perception is impermanent … Volitional
formations are impermanent … … Consciousness is impermanent,
conditioned, dependently arisen, subject to destruction, to vanishing,
to fading away, to cessation. Through its cessation, cessation is spoken of.
SN 22.21


What’s impermanent is suffering.
Yadaniccaṁ taṁ dukkhaṁ;
What’s suffering has ceased and ended.’
yaṁ dukkhaṁ taṁ niruddhaṁ tadatthaṅgatan’ti.
SN 22.85


“Oh! Conditions are impermanent,
“Aniccā vata saṅkhārā,
their nature is to rise and fall;
uppādavayadhammino;
having arisen, they cease;
Uppajjitvā nirujjhanti,
their stilling is true bliss.”
tesaṁ vūpasamo sukho”ti.
DN 16


‘Boil’ is a term for this body made up of the four primary elements,
produced by mother and father, built up from rice and porridge, liable
to impermanence, to wearing away and erosion, to breaking up and
destruction.
Gaṇḍoti kho, bhikkhave, imassetaṁ cātumahābhūtikassa kāyassa
adhivacanaṁ mātāpettikasambhavassa odanakummāsūpacayassa
aniccucchādanaparimaddanabhedanaviddhaṁsanadhammassa.
AN 9.15


‘Conditions fall apart. Persist with diligence.’
These were the Realized One’s last words.
DN 16


When the Buddha became fully extinguished... the mendicants who were free of desire endured, mindful and aware, thinking, “Conditions are impermanent (aniccā). How could it possibly be otherwise?”
DN 16


Inconstancy means constantly changing. It's in the quote. Nothing about continuing to exist and getting reborn.

Hello. My question intended for answers quoting the Pali suttas.

You've misdefined the English term inconstancy in the question. You've also misrepresented the definition of inconstancy in your own provided quote. This renders the question poorly-framed and answering it problematic.

Hello. The quote provided is your post. I have quoted you.

Yes and misrepresented the definition given by me for the term in your next sentence where you misdefine the term.
